# Python - Exported data to CSV in loop only saves last line of output

Tags: python, csv

I have a dictionary of game names within the variable gameList. From there I can successfully print each game name, but when attempting to save each game in the list into a CSV, it will only save the last game name that is outputted, not the entire list.

```
for i in gameList:
    #print(games[i]['name'])
    csvGames = games[i]['name']
    with open('exportedGamesList.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        for line in csvGames:
            csvfile.write(line)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hint: you're re-writing the file for each game.

Comment: Ah, I need to append! Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You should append to the file
`with open('exportedGamesList.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:`